# Send embed commands with command handler

Tags: discord.js

So I'm building a bot with `discord.js`, but I'm having trouble sending commands that include embed. I can send text commands easily, such as `purge`, `ping`, `time` and so on, but having trouble with embeds.

This is my `index.js` file

```js
const keepAlive = require('./server');
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client(); 
var { readdirSync } = require('fs'); 

client.config = require('./config.js'); 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection(); 

for(const file of readdirSync('./commands/')) { 
  if(!file.endsWith(".js")) return; 
  var fileName = file.substring(0, file.length - 3); 

  var fileContents = require(`./commands/${file}`); 
  client.commands.set(fileName, fileContents); 
}



for(const file of readdirSync('./events/')) { 
  if(!file.endsWith(".js")) return; 
  var fileName = file.substring(0, file.length - 3); 
  
  var fileContents = require(`./events/${file}`); 

  client.on(fileName, fileContents.bind(null, client)); 
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(`./events/${file}`)]; 
}

client.login(client.config.token) 
  .then(() => { 
    if(!client.user.bot) { console.log("[JPBTips] Don't self bot idot"); return process.exit() }; 
    console.log(`Client logged in as ${client.user.tag}`); 
  })
  .catch((err) => { 
    console.error("Error while logging in: " + err); 
    if(err.toString().match(/incorrect login details/gi)) console.log("Make sure to change up your config!"); 
  });
keepAlive();
```

And then this is my `message.js` code:

```js
module.exports = (client, message) => { 
  if(!message.content.startsWith(client.config.prefix)) return; 
  if(message.author.bot) return; 
  
  const args = message.content.slice(client.config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g); 
  
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase() 
  
  var cmd = client.commands.get(command);
  if(!cmd) return; 

  cmd(client, message, args); 
}
```

Comment: If i dont answer fast, sorry on vaca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should take a look at the docs for the [embedBuilder](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html)

If you are using discord.js v14 you should use `const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');`
and if you are using discord.js v13 use `const { EmbedBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');`

**That means your command file (located in your commands folder) should look something like this:**

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js'); //depending on your discord.js version (this example is for v14)

exports.run = (client, message) => {
    const exampleEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor(0x0099FF)
        .setTitle('Some title')
        .setURL('https://discord.js.org/')
        .setAuthor({ name: 'Some name', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png', url: 'https://discord.js.org' })
        .setDescription('Some description here')
        .setThumbnail('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Regular field title', value: 'Some value here' },
            { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
        )
        .addFields({ name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true })
        .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: 'Some footer text here', iconURL: 'https://i.imgur.com/AfFp7pu.png' });

    message.reply({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
}
```

And in your message.js file you have to replace `cmd(client, message, args)` with `cmd.run(client, message, args);`

Please let me know if this works out for you and have a great vacation

Answer (score 0):

can you show the file where you're trying to reply with an embed ?

Maybe the problem (without seeing your code) is:

You're writing: `message.reply(embed);`

But since V13 it's: `message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question and should be a comment only. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).